# Identical Bootstrap Columns Align / Format Differently

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried one answer found on this site, which was to put rows inside a row, but it didn't work.

The problem I'm having is while the code is identical, the columns align differently. On a medium or large screen, the labels for the second column seem to pull to the left. The space between label and field is different, the spacing between form groups is off too. On a xs screen, the fields in the second column have a shorter width.

The code is pasted below. I'm trying to get the alignment to be identical to how it appears in the first column.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">     
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row box">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" role="form">    

                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label for="claimant1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Claimant 1</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claimant1" name="claimant1" placeholder="Enter 1st Claimant">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="gender" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male</label>
                                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</label>           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label for="age1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DOB</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="age1" name="age1" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </div> <!-- /row -->    
                </div> <!-- /column -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" >        
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label for="claimant2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Claimant 2</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claimant2" name="claimant2" placeholder="Enter 2nd Claimant">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="gender2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender2" value="Male">Male</label>
                                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender2" value="Female">Female</label>           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label for="age2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DOB</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="age2" name="age2" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>        
                    </div>  <!-- /row -->
                </div> <!-- /column -->  
            </div> <!-- / row box -->
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the form tag, here is your updated code

```
<html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title> </title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row box">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="claimant1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Claimant 1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claimant1" name="claimant1" placeholder="Enter 1st Claimant">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="age1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DOB</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="age1" name="age1" placeholder="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /column -->

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="claimant2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Claimant 2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claimant2" name="claimant2" placeholder="Enter 2nd Claimant">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender2" value="Male">Male</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender2" value="Female">Female</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="age2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DOB</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="age2" name="age2" placeholder="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /column -->

      </div>
      <!-- / row box -->
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I missed the closing form tag in my posted code. However, in my actual project I have 2 total rows and 2 columns in each row. I was still getting the bad alignment even with the closing form tag. Then I realized, perhaps a form class cannot span multiple rows. I condensed the form class to one row and it aligns properly now.